# Javascript drawing / geom libraries

Tags: javascript, graphics, vector, drawing, draw

I would like to make a vector graphics editor in javascript (lighter version of inkscape) as my university project. I have done some research about basic js drawing libraries, right now I am planning to use jcanvas, but I am not entirely sure if it will be sufficient enough. If you know any better libraries, please let me know.

Peace,

Jimmy

Comment: Why not just use SVG for vector graphics - a library might be, e.g., Raphael for that.

Comment: you can see svg-edit... http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.5.1/editor/svg-editor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML5 canvas is a raster graphics (meaning pixel-based) drawing API. Therefore, it is not best suited for developing an SVG editor.

As far as SVG libraries go, [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) is an excellent SVG library for JavaScript. I contend that it may be the best choice in your case.